# How to forbid gdb from hanging?

Tags: gdb

```
169         sigsuspend(&set);
(gdb)
```

As you see ,after executing `syssuspend(&set);` gdb will hang ,how can I have a chance to type any commands?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to debug several processes running the same executable (a.out), you want the (relatively) new GDB [multi-inferior support](http://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Inferiors-and-Programs.html).